# FloatingActionButton icon animation

Tags: android, animation, floating-action-button, android-vectordrawable

I tried to implement animation of FAB icon. I made everything exactly as described in the documentation, however my icon doesn't animate. I don't know what I'm missing.

Please take a look at codes under this [Gist link](https://gist.github.com/ogasimli/7cb78dc12b1d7bf94c65).

Please help me!

Comment: I use this library https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button its easy and simple

Comment: Please specify what animation you which to implement

Comment: I want to implement 360 degrees roatation

Answer (score 1):

[image: adding Ripple to FAB button]

Please check this code and replicate the same for getting animation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following and supply to the background attribute.

```
<ripple xmlns:android=........
android:color="?android:colorControlhighlight">
<item> 
<shape android:shape:.....>
</item>
</ripple>
```

Comment: Could you explain more detailed? Whre do I need to add this and why?

Comment: I have added a code snippet below. enjoy! For more on the material design check this tutorial: https://www.udacity.com/course/material-design-for-android-developers--ud862 and check samples here: : https://github.com/udacity/ud862-samples

Comment: What you explained is for ImageButton and this for changing the elevation when pressed. I use FloatingActionButton and I want to rotate 360 degree the image below the FAB. Please take a look at the code: https://gist.github.com/ogasimli/7cb78dc12b1d7bf94c65